# Automatically rendering shared view as part of master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

I have a shared view located in Shared/Header.aspx and I want to render this as part of the HeaderContent ContentPlaceHolder.  My master page contains:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" />
```

and I want to be able to tell MVC to populate that content place holder with the Shared/Header view, which contains:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
    ....
</asp:Content>
```

At the moment in each of the pages where I want the HeaderContent to be populated (and on some pages I don't want it to be) I do this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("Header"); %>
</asp:Content>
```

Is there any way I can effectively do the above but from the Controller handling the request (or a child class of ViewPage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this from the controller, then you could pass a property in the ViewData, which could be picked up from the layout page. E.g. in a controller action:

```
ViewData["ShowHeader"] = true;
```

Then in the layout page you could say

```
<% if(ViewData["ShowHeader"] != null && ((bool)ViewData["ShowHeader"]))
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Header");
} %>
```

That way you don't need the extra content placeholder too.

Comment: The problem is if I use Html.RenderPartial in the master page, it attempts to use the master page to render the partial content and causes a stack overflow (because it's recursing).  I just want to render the HeaderContent without also having it wrapped in a master page when rendered.

Comment: I got it working; I had to remove the MasterPageFile in the header and footer views (since I had just copied from existing pages).  It works perfectly fine now :)